# Just Curious: How does Entity Framework determines the naming of a join table in m:n relationships?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am curious how Entity Framework determines the naming of a join table in m:n relationships.

Context:

I have a Student and Course class as below. When testing out in a VS solution, EF generates the join table as StudentCourses.

My question: **Why EF generate the join table as StudentCourses and not CourseStudents? How is the naming of the join table determined?**

Example code:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find it completely, but here is the begining.

When your DbContext creates its model, [OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) is called. This has a parameter which is a [DbModelBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

This DbModelBuilder has [Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.conventions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) of type [ConventionsConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.conventionsconfiguration?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).
You would think we are almost there. Alas, the ConventionsConfiguration has no property to access the conventions.

If you look at the [source code of DbModelBuilder](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/240467565cdd10a28cdd8e256f163670e84cfdcc/src/EntityFramework/DbModelBuilder.cs#L94), you can see that the conventions are initialize with `V2ConventionSet.Conventions`. You have to do some deep digging, but then you can find that the [V2ConventionSet](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17903519/) is derived from [V1ConventionsSet](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17903518/). The vast majority of Conventions is in V1ConventionSet.

Alas, although the names of the Conventions in the ConventionSet are fairly descriptive, I cannot find a Convention that defines how the junction table name is defined.

Using Reflection, you can see that the ConventionConfiguration has some non-public fields

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var conventions = modelBuilder.Conventions;
    var conventionsType = conventions.GetType();
    var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    var fields = conventionsType.GetFields(flags);
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        var conventionValue = field.GetValue(conventions);
        if (conventionValue is IEnumerable sequence)
        {
            foreach (var item in sequence)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This also doesn't help a lot, you can only see that the Conventions are the ones that we found in V2ConventionSet. Maybe if you examine the conventions you may find the one that combines the names. Maybe the one that defines plural names?

Anyway, you can add your own convention, and you can see what happens:

```
public class JunctionTableConvention : IStoreModelConvention<AssociationType>
{
    public void Apply(AssociationType item, DbModel model)
    {
        var associations = model.ConceptualToStoreMapping.AssociationSetMappings;

        foreach (var association in associations)
        {
            var associationSetEnds = association.AssociationSet.AssociationSetEnds;
            association.StoreEntitySet.Table = String.Format("{0}_{1}",
                GetTableName(associationSetEnds[0].EntitySet.ElementType),
                GetTableName(associationSetEnds[1].EntitySet.ElementType));
        }
    }

    private string GetTableName(EntityType type)
    {
        var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
            .Replace(type.Name, ".[A-Z]", m => m.Value[0] + "_" + m.Value[1]);
        return result.ToLower();
    }
}
```

Add this convention in OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new JunctionTableConvention());
    ...
}
```

In your program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var dbContext = new SchoolDbContext())
    {
        dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
    }
}
```

Your debugger will show you that OnModelCreating is called, where the junction table convention is added. After OnModelCreating returns, JunctionModel.Apply is called.

I have a many-to-many between Students and Teachers. the AssociationType is a `{CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Teacher_Students_Source}`.

My code gets the AssociationSetMappings. There is only one such mapping.
This mapping has a StoreEntitySet which has a string property Table which has the value "TeacherStudents"

My code gets the AssociationSetEnds to find the types of the DbSets, and constructs a nice name for this table. This name is put in association.StoreEntitySet.Table.

So one of the other conventions already has filled in this value with "TeacherStudents".
To find out which convention did this, I could remove the conventions one by one, and see when the name changes.

But I left that for you to do.

Another method of course is to look in the reference sources of all these conventions and see which one defines the name of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the lead! I was thinking about Conventions too but did not trace it as deeply as you did!